# AndEngine visible rectangle

Tags: entity, andengine, visibility, scene, drawrectangle

I'm trying to create an additional visibility rectangle on a main Scene.
So I'v a main Camera 480x800 that is showing me a scene as it is and i'd like to attach an aditional entity or a scene that will have a rectangle of visibility.
So if I'll drag items inside it they will not dissapier in a single moment they will dissapier gradually.
[image]

Comment: Hi, I wrote a container class here with an example of how to use it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560616/custom-scrollview-in-andengine/16618073#16618073 There is a SetAlphaPadding() method, (as  shapes approach the boundries of the container, their alpha decreases), that may be similar to what you are looking for or you may be able to tweak it to get what you want.

Comment: Also I am not saying this is the only way but have you tried stamping out a square alpha hole in your background? I have done similar in one of my own games. The background is then set to z order 1 and everything 'inside' the square is set to z order 0. You can then set the square background to match the actual background to make it seamless. Any content outside the square will be rendered over.

Comment: Such a good idea, I'll try it dude. But still not clear about how to do that... But i'll try

Answer (score 2):

As described in my previous comment you could stamp out a square alpha hole in your background Sprite. You could do this simply with an image editor, adding alpha pixels or you could do it dynamically as follows,

```
//set the background to white - so we can see our square alpha
//cut out later
mScene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

//Create and load bitmap texture atlas
BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapBGTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA); 
mActivity.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTextures(mBitmapBGTextureAtlas);


//Get image in assets and decode into bitmap
InputStream ims;
try {
    ims = mActivity.getAssets().open("gfx/my_backgound.jpg");
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}   
Bitmap Bitmap_bg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);

//In my case the image is different than the height and width of the camera
//so store the ratio of size and height that the image will be resized to
float XScale = Bitmap_bg.getWidth()/mCamera.getWidth();
float YScale = Bitmap_bg.getHeight()/mCamera.getHeight();

//Cut out the alpha square, if our camera is 480x800, the square will appear
//at (40,200) and will be size 400x400
Bitmap_bg = cutSquareOutOfBitmap(Bitmap_bg, 40 * XScale, 200 * YScale, 400 * XScale , 400 * YScale);

//Get our edited bitmap into a region of the texture atlas
BitmapTextureAtlasSource source = new BitmapTextureAtlasSource(Bitmap_bg);
mBackground = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(mBitmapBGTextureAtlas, source, 0, 0);
Bitmap_bg.recycle();

//Finally, create our background sprite with this new texture region
Sprite mBackgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, mCamera.getWidth(), mCamera.getHeight(), mBackground);
mBackgroundSprite.setZIndex(1);
mScene.attachChild(mBackgroundSprite);
```

And the function cutSquareOutOfBitmap()

```
public static Bitmap cutSquareOutOfBitmap(Bitmap MyImage,  float Xpos,  float Ypos, float Width, float Height) { 

    Bitmap mBitmap = MyImage.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint mPaint = new Paint(); 

    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap ); 

     mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);          
    mPaint .setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT));  
    mPaint .setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 

    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap , 0, 0, null); 
    mCanvas.drawRect(Xpos, Ypos, Xpos + Width, Ypos + Height, mPaint ); 

    return mBitmap ;
}
```

If you run this - not a lot to look at but a big white square, however, this is a transparent region, the square is actually the background we set earlier.

To demonstrate how the contents will be obscured, you could create a scrollable area, as mentioned in my previous comment I wrote a small container class you are welcome to use,

[Custom ScrollView in andengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560616/custom-scrollview-in-andengine/16618073#16618073)

Underneath the first code block in this answer, after,

```
mScene.attachChild(mBackgroundSprite);
```

You could now add,

```
//Now we can use the ShapeScrollContainer just as an example so the user can
//scroll our container shapes around

//Create it around the same area as the cut out
ShapeScrollContainer mShapeScrollContainer = new ShapeScrollContainer(40, 200, 400, 400, new IShapeScrollContainerTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public void OnContentClicked(Shape pShape) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Add code here for content click event
    }

});

//Disable the ShapeScrollContainer ability to change the visibility
//of contents - we no longer require this as the background will
//cover them outside of the bounds of the ShapeScrollContainer itself
mShapeScrollContainer.SetContentVisiblitiyControl(false);
//Disable alpha
mShapeScrollContainer.SetAlphaVisiblitiyControl(false);
//Allow user to scroll both horizontally and vertically
mShapeScrollContainer.SetScrollableDirections(true, true);
//Don't allow the user to scroll to no where
mShapeScrollContainer.SetScrollLock(true);
//Allow use to scroll half the container over in either direction
mShapeScrollContainer.SetScrollLockPadding(50.0f,50.0f);
//Attach the container to the scene and register the event listener
mScene.registerTouchArea(mShapeScrollContainer);
mScene.attachChild(mShapeScrollContainer);

//Finally add some content to the container, what ever extends Shape,
//Sprite, Animated Sprite, Text, ChangeableText e.t.c.

Rectangle mRectangle = new Rectangle(200, 360, 80, 80);
mRectangle.setColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
mRectangle.setZIndex(0);    
//Attach to the scene and the ShapeScrollContainer
mScene.attachChild(mRectangle);
mShapeScrollContainer.Add(mRectangle);

Rectangle mRectangle2 = new Rectangle(40, 360, 80, 80);
mRectangle2.setColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
mRectangle2.setZIndex(0);
mScene.attachChild(mRectangle2);
mShapeScrollContainer.Add(mRectangle2);

Rectangle mRectangle3 = new Rectangle(360, 360, 80, 80);
mRectangle3.setColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
mRectangle3.setZIndex(0);
mScene.attachChild(mRectangle3);
mShapeScrollContainer.Add(mRectangle3);

//And sort the order in which shapes are rendered
mScene.sortChildren();
```

Now you should get something like the following after scrolling,

[image: Screen Shots while Scrolling]

As another alternative if you are going for a simpler background you could forgo the bitmap manipulation and simply make the square with four surrounding rectangles making up the sides to the edge of the screen.

Or you could physically split your background into 4 surrounding rectangles and a central square with an image editor. Then create 5 sprites, set the z order of the four rectangles to 2, the square to 0 and any content sprites to 1.

Hope this is of use.