# AndEngine GLES2 ScrollContainer

Tags: andengine

How to create scrollable block in AndEngine GLES2? 
I found solution for AndEngine GLES1 here [Custom ScrollView in andengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560616/custom-scrollview-in-andengine)
but it doesn't work for GLES2 (I changed Shape object on RectangularShape for GLES2)
That what i need, on screenshot

---

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Default settings for ShapeScrollContainer looks like this (text not visable). Green it is scrollbar

---

[image]

---

If i commend code in func ShapeScrollContainer.SetShapeAlpha, it's look (scroll doesn't work)

---

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details on what "doesn't work"?

Comment: It's work without errors, but block (and text in block) not displayed

Comment: That what i do with ShapeScrollContainer.java
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19153875/ShapeScrollContainer.java

And call in code
`code`

Comment: `code`        
final Text mMessage = new Text(
                x_from,
                y_from,
                font,
                text,
                EvoEvo.getInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mMessage.setVisible(true);
        mMessage.setZIndex(10);
        mMessage.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        scene.attachChild(mMessage);

`code`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.
ShapeScrollContainer does not work correctly with large (multi-line) blocks.
I just explode the multiline text on different objects (one-line)
Like this

---

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Text text = new Text(
                x_from,
                y_from + ( 30 * i ),
                font,
                "Scrolling..." + i,
                getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        text.setVisible(true);
        text.setZIndex(10);
        text.setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        scene.attachChild(text);
        ScrollableArea.Add(text);
    }
```

Comment: I'm tryng to use the ShapeScrollContainer class with a long multiline text, but it is not working. As I can see here in your answer, it works only for a single line text?